# How to build custom pages in CRM Dynamics?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am a beginner to CRM Dynamics. I want to build a web page in CRM Dynamics. Example like Registration page, Listing page of users i.e. any page which displays data based of custom business logic and pages should be authorized only to authorized users.

I just want to build site just like we do with Salesforce using visualforce pages and custom apex classes and all.

How to achieve same thing in CRM Dynamics? and what are ways to achieve this?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. To get started you might want to check out the [Dynamics 365 Developer's Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/developer-guide). After you start coding, if you hit any snags, feel free to post new questions with your code.

Comment: Can you just guide me with the topics I have to read ?

Comment: From what you're looking to do, you should be searching for "Custom web resource", "web api", and possibly "client api". Also please note that if you're building stuff for CRM users, you should first look at configuring out-of-box forms, views, and dashboards. When building for external users, you may also want to consider the Portal.

Answer (score 0):

The **Sitemap** allows you to bind to a custom webresource.
You might want to start by adding to your Stitemap an item that links you to your custom HTML page and then work with json, jquery, for your business logic.
From the HTML you can call actions using [Process.js](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=processjs) and run C# logic.

Alternatively you can consider Portal.

Answer (score 0):

I often use the WebApi endpoint, an html web ressource and a single-page application javascript framework, like Knockout, to achieve this.

The important is to host every component as a web ressource or use a CDN.